# Problems with CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL

Tags: ios, swift, image, cgimage

I'm using CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL for saving a gif image, here is the code that I have:

```
func gifFromImages(images: Array<UIImage>, animationTime: Double) -> String? {
        let date = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

        let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/gifs/" + String(date) + ".gif"        

        let delay = animationTime / Double(totalFrames)

        let prep = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String :
               [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String : delay]] as CFDictionary

        let fileProperties = [ kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String : 
                               [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String : 0] ,
                               kCGImageMetadataShouldExcludeGPS as String: true]
                               as CFDictionary

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) as CFURL

        guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeGIF, 
                                images.count, nil) else {
                return nil
        }

        CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties)

        for image in images {
            if let cgImage = image.cgImage {
                CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage, prep)
            }
        }

        if CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) {
            return path
        }

        return nil
    }
```

The problem that I'm facing is that when I try this code on the simulator, it works fine and it creates the file that I need, but when I run this on a device, the CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL return nil.
My first thought is that the path to the file is not the correct one, I've looked online and I try with the following paths/urls:

```
let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/gifs/" + String(date) + ".gif"

let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last!.appending("/gifs/\(String(date)).gif")

let path = NSString(string: "~/gifs/\(String(date)).gif").expandingTildeInPath

let url = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true) as CFURL
```

And when I tried to use URL(string: path) instead of URL(fileURLWithPath:) i got the following error:

> : CGDataConsumer(url_close): write failed.

Any ideas of what could be happening? Which path should I be using?

Comment: An app's bundle is read-only on real devices.

Comment: do you know where can I store the image that I'm creating ?

Comment: If it's temporary, use the Caches folder. If it's more permanent, use the Documents folder.

Comment: @RodrigoGonzalez https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna answer this question in case anyone else steps into this problem. After some research and using the information on the comments, I found out the solution. I've ended up using:

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
           .userDomainMask, true).last?.appending("/\(String(date)).gif")
```

The problem with my first solution was that it added a folder after the Document directory and the file name.